Is it possible to COUNT(*) a table with a bloom filter? Clickhouse
I can't call the COUNT function with Clickhouse and a bloom filter quickly.
I have a table with Clickhouse which has a bloom filter so that I can search for text, but when I try to use the COUNT function, the response is very long.
Here is my schema and my request:
CREATE TABLE logs
(
    `id` UUID DEFAULT generateUUIDv4(),
    `name` LowCardinality(String),
    `discord` LowCardinality(String),
    `license` LowCardinality(String),
    `event` String,
    `category` LowCardinality(String),
    `created_at` DateTime('Europe/Paris') DEFAULT now(),
    INDEX event_index (event) TYPE tokenbf_v1(9815, 7, 0) GRANULARITY 1
)
ENGINE = MergeTree
PARTITION BY category
ORDER BY created_at;

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM logs WHERE hasToken(event, 'Proin') SETTINGS use_query_cache=true


The partition key doesn't look great. What is the cardinality of category? Have you tried removing the partitioning?

The category field can take a maximum of 50 different values. I've created another table without the partition and with 10 times less data (so 100 million), it takes 10 seconds to run the query.

It would be difficult to know the exact issue without knowing the actual values of event and what the resulting Bloom filter looks like. I suppose you could try a higher GRANULARiTY. Or tweak the size or number of hash functions. It definitely won't be fast with 50 partitions, but yours is slow with 1 part so it's not a helpful index either way. I would think a brute force method like position would be faster than 10 seconds.

The event field is a Lorem Ipsum string of around 500 characters. If I search for a word like "hello", my query will return all rows containing that word. So I think the filter response is boolean? The position function doesn't help but I'll try the other two remarks, thanks.
